# Heroku does not update

Tags: angular, heroku

I'm using Heroku but it seems like that it does not update my code everytime I push it to the master.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

But after I do this nothing happens.... The output after I push it to the master:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 494 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.9.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.8
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > angular2-express-slim@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_dcfbba691d5c6f4b81e12dbe7f938c55
remote:        > npm run build:prod
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > angular2-express-slim@0.0.0 build:prod /tmp/build_dcfbba691d5c6f4b81e12dbe7f938c55
remote:        > node bin/bundler.js --prod
remote:        
remote:        Unhandled rejection Error on fetch for app/main.js at file:///tmp/build_dcfbba691d5c6f4b81e12dbe7f938c55/app/main.js
remote:        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_dcfbba691d5c6f4b81e12dbe7f938c55/app/main.js'
remote:        at Error (native)
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── @angular/common@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/compiler@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/core@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/forms@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/http@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/platform-browser@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/router@3.1.2
remote:        ├── @angular/upgrade@2.1.2
remote:        ├── @types/core-js@0.9.35
remote:        ├── @types/node@6.0.60
remote:        ├── angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17
remote:        ├── body-parser@1.13.3
remote:        ├── compression@1.6.2
remote:        ├── cookie-parser@1.3.5
remote:        ├── core-js@2.4.1
remote:        ├── debug@2.2.0
remote:        ├── express@4.13.4
remote:        ├── morgan@1.6.1
remote:        ├── reflect-metadata@0.1.9
remote:        ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
remote:        ├── systemjs-builder@0.15.34
remote:        ├── typescript@2.1.5
remote:        ├── yargs@4.8.1
remote:        └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.26
remote:        
remote:  !     Unmet dependencies don't fail npm install but may cause runtime issues
remote:        https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 35.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://something.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/something.git
   fd25f32..505de47  master -> master
```

The strange thing is that somehow I managed to deploy it but don't know how I really did it. ALso when I look at when I deployed the last one was a time ago.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no output after trying to push?

Comment: I edited my post for a bit more information!

Comment: Hmm are any of those unmet dependencies required?

Comment: It looks like it is pushing and building, what leads you to believe it isn't changing anything?

Comment: Well the problem is that my template attribute in one of my components doesn't change. Also if I check the deploy time it doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Heroku's free version of Dyno(instance in Heroku term), it sleeps after 30 minutes of inactivity. That case, you need to hit your instance's URL so that Dyno can awake from sleeping.

Your Heroku command looks correct and Heroku should create new release and push it to the Dyno. Try

```
heroku releases
```

in your Heroku CLI and see if your latest change is released as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your edited files are in the last commit (`git status`)